# Set the form width and height for form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there is any way to specify the width and height of a form when using `form_for`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest way is to set an ID or class for the form, and set the width and height for the form using CSS.  In your view:

```
<% form_for ..., :html => { :class => "myform" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Set the width and height of the form in `public/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
form.myform {
    width: 75%;
    height: 500px;
    /* Or fill in whatever width and height values you need */
}
```

Lastly, make sure that the `application.css` stylesheet is included in your HTML layout.  Your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` should contain a line like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

A final note: Be careful about setting a specific height to your forms.  If the form's content doesn't fit within the specified height, your form probably won't look as intended.  You can prevent this by setting `overflow: scroll` in your stylesheet right after the width and height declarations, but in most cases you're probably better off letting the form occupy the height it needs.

Comment: I am new to web programming so know little about css. And where should I put the css? I would be nice if you would be able to provide me a complete solution so that I can follow step by step.Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with some additional details.  Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. I concur. Although it is possible to set width & height attributes, or even inline styles with a helper, it is best practise to separate your presentational layer (CSS) from the structural (HTML).